# React Context Api and State hooks mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modern react application using the context api and many hooks, i use the context to store global values for my application, this values or the context itself should never directly re-render other components, the context itself has a its own getter/setter in form of the UseState hook/s which is what is called from the consumer components to be used, if any component is dependent on the context data a separate state in this component itself is created and state is then being properly handled.

My concrete question in my case how bad is it to directly mutate the object i have stored in the context?

for example from any random consumer component changing the context object as follows:

```
const handlerFunction = () => {contextObjData.value = "Something"};
```

Instead of the "intended" react way:

```
const handlerFunction = () => {setContextObjData(...contextObjData, value: "Something")};
```

To me it seems overkill to each time save the entire object again but maybe someone can give me another perspective and some insights.

Side question kind of nooby but i am not sure, is there a difference between these two:

```
const handlerFunction = () => {setContextObjData(...contextObjData, value: "Something")};


const handlerFunction = () => {setContextObjData(prevState => ({...contextObjData, value: "Something"}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A state change will trigger a render. When you mutate something then React won't detect that the state has changed and will not re render.

The handlerFunction examples matter only if you want to optimize it using useCallback but the way you do it it is broken either way (syntax error and not using prevState in the second example).

```
//handlerFunction will be re created every render
const handlerFunction = () =>
  setContextObjData({
    ...contextObjData,
    value: 'Something',
  });
//handler function will only be created on mount
const optimizedHandler = React.useCallback(
  () =>
    setContextObjData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      value: 'Something',
    })),
  [] //empty dependency, only create optimizedHandler on mount
);
//broken handler, using stale closure will give you liner warning
const brokenHandler = React.useCallback(
  () =>
    //callback only used on mount so has contextObjData
    //  as it was when mounted (stale closure)
    setContextObjData({
      ...contextObjData, //needs contextObjData in closure scope
      value: 'Something',
    }),
  [] //empty dependency, but contextObjData will be a stale closure
);
```

Pure components will only re render when props change, state change or return value from useSelector or useContext change.

When you pass a callback as a prop to a child and your component re renders without the child needing to re render you can optimize a passed callback with useCallback so the child doesn't get needlessly re rendered:

```js
//Child is a pure component
const Child = React.memo(function Increment({ increment }) {
  const r = React.useRef(0);
  r.current++;
  return (
    <button onClick={increment}>
      rendered: {r.current} times, click to increment
    </button>
  );
});
const Parent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);
  const increment = React.useCallback(
    () => setCount((c) => c + 1),
    []
  );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const t = setInterval(() => increment(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(t);
  }, [increment]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{count}</h4>
      <Child increment={increment} />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is an example how mutation will break re rendering:

```js
const CounterContext = React.createContext();
const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('render counter provider');
  const [c, setC] = React.useState({ count: 0 });
  const increment = React.useCallback(
    () =>
      setC((c) => {
        console.log('broken:', c.count);
        c.count++;
        return c;
      }), //broken, context users never re render
    []
  );
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={[c, increment]}>
      {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  console.log('render App');
  const [count, increment] = React.useContext(
    CounterContext
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>count: {count.count}</h4>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <CounterProvider>
    <App />
  </CounterProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but i just wanted to know if in my case i have to worry about mutating my context object since no state is planned to change with the data stored in here and then the difference between the last two examples.

Comment: @Steytz I added an example that shows mutating context does not cause re render and will break your app. Not sure what you mean with you won't change but need to mutate, doesn't mutation change the data? The example in your question would, it would not cause any re renders though so no component using that data is updated.

Comment: I am very thankful for the reply and in normal circumstances this will totally make sense, i just use the context to store some global data not a single one of my components will get re rendered or should get re rendered if this data changes, so in this specific case is me setting from time to time this context data directly like **contextObjData.value = "Something"** still bad ?

Comment: @Steytz When you never use context in components then it's pointless to have the context but you can mutate it without a problem.

Comment: I use it to store data globally so all components can have access to this global data  most of the things in there are just for the components to consume not to change hence it will not re render anything, for example data such as which questions have already been answered in a quiz or which is the actual question and such, i basically use it to have a place to store data amongst all my components which i then persist to a db but as you see this is secondary informative data which doesn't directly affect the state cycle of any component.

Comment: For the components which these data might affect the rendering i still have a separate State for that component for which i set the contextData as the default value and from there make changes as usual to the normal state

Comment: @Steytz If component do not need to re render when you mutate data then it would not be a problem. If they do need to re render when mutating then the last example in my question shows that that may be a problem

Comment: Thanks, for the replies!